# in Ember with two query params, why does the second query param disappear when i manually set the other one?

Tags: ember.js

i have query params set up on a route.

```
SomeController
  queryParams: ['foo', 'bar']

SomeRoute
  queryParams:
    foo:
      refreshModel: true
    bar:
     refreshModel: true
```

the url initially looks like http://blahblah.com/some?foo=123&bar=456

but when i set a param on the controller like someController.set('bar',666), the foo param disappears after the transition, http://blahblah.com/some?bar=666

how do i keep all query params intact when i change just one?  i've also tried a controller.setProperties() to set them all at the same time, but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can use different variable to set in controller and while transition to other route using those params then do not set them in same variables.

```
        var options = {};
        options['foo'] = 123;
        options['bar'] = 666;
        this.transitionToRoute(someRoute, {
            "queryParams": options
        });
```